# C function of custom x86 kernel accessing char* gives random value

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, kernel, osdev

I am writing a custom kernel for x86 in C. Whenever I try to access a value from a `char*` I get a random value.

```
void test(char input[]) {
    char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
    *video_memory = input[0];
}

void main() {
    test("ba");
}
```

This seems like I should get 'b' to print, but it gives some random symbol.

Same for this

```
void test() {
    char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
    char* val = "ba";
    *video_memory =  val[0];
}

void main() {
    test();
}
```

But not this

```
void test() {
    char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
    *video_memory =  "ba"[0];
}

void main() {
    test();
}
```

That last one works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Here is how I set up my stack

```
[BITS 32]
init_pm:                       
    mov ax, DATA_SEG        
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000       
    mov esp, ebp               
    
    call BEGIN_PM

BEGIN_PM:
    call KERNEL_OFFSET    
    jmp $
```

Comment: WAG - your stack is not setup correctly.   Btw, video memory is char,attr; so it should be video_memory[0] = "ba"[0]; video_memory[1] = 0x70;

Comment: @mevets see my edit, how is my stack set up here wrong?

Comment: Yes that is correct @Michael Petch. I figured that out right before your comment. Only if I had seen that question a full day ago...

Comment: In x86-64 machine code, static data will usually be addressed with RIP-relative addressing.  When that machine code is executed in 32-bit mode, that encoding has its old meaning of a 32-bit absolute address, rather than a 32-bit relative offset.

Comment: @CalW : not a problem. Unless you know what to look for you may have easily missed it. I only knew what to look for since I have written answers on the subject in the past. I upvoted your answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! The problem was not at all to do with my code, but the way I generated binaries.

My original method:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c kernel.o
nasm kernel_entry.ASM -f elf64 -o kernel_entry.o
ld -o kernel.bin -T linker.l kernel_entry.o kernel.o --oformat binary
nasm -f bin -o bootloader_s1.bin bootloader_s1.ASM
cat bootloader_s1.bin kernel.bin > os-image
```

My new method:

```
gcc -m32 -fno-pie -ffreestanding -c kernel.c kernel.o
nasm kernel_entry.ASM -f elf -o kernel_entry.o
ld -m elf_i386 -o kernel.bin -T linker.l kernel_entry.o kernel.o --oformat binary
nasm -f bin -o bootloader_s1.bin bootloader_s1.ASM
cat bootloader_s1.bin kernel.bin > os-image
```

I believe it was because I was compiling as 64 bit when my code is made to run in 32 bits.